# Getting "Route not enabled for account" error while sending api activity request

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

When trying to getting response from `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/bim360/admin/v1/projects/:projectId/activities` it rises 403 error with details - Route not enabled for account. But, for example, request `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/bim360/admin/v1/projects/:projectId/users` has successfully responsed. User has all admin permissions.

Can every one help with that? :) Are there another ways to get project activities?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please update your question and provide a MRE (stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 
with relevant code parts.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, [activity API](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/bim360/admin/v1/projects/:projectId/activities) is not released yet, so you cannot use it currently. Please stay tuned with our official announcement in the further. Apologies for the inconvenience!