# Project Activities available for public

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

This was asked in 2020 and I saw there is a beta for it:
[Getting "Route not enabled for account" error while sending api activity request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64012368/getting-route-not-enabled-for-account-error-while-sending-api-activity-request)

Is there any update on when this Beta will be available?
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360-private/v1/reference/http/admin-projectsprojectidactivities-GET/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, according to our engineering team, Project Activities API private beta is not available anymore. For getting activity data, please use   Data Connector API instead. We apologize for the inconvenience.

Here is the announcement of Data Connector API for activities support.

https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/accbim-360-insight-data-connector-api-supports-activities